# Retrieving dependency from Stanford dependencies

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

neg(not-2,happy-5)

do anyone know how I can obtain just "neg" from this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's **no-brainer** if you have at least begun with regex.

Comment: One does not need to know much if one can [use Google](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=split%20with%20parentheses%20java).

Answer (score 0):

1. use [java#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to split the string from '('
2. Split method will return array
3. array with index 0 will contain neg

   ```
   String x="neg(not-2,happy-5)";
   System.out.println(x.split("\\(")[0]);
   ```

http://ideone.com/hKfaEx